# Python difflib getting coherent data from ndiff instead of plain strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare, comparison, diff

The project I am working on involves running a compare algorithm on 2 versions of the same file and the writing the results to a single log.

I am trying to use `difflib.ndiff` for this as I want the exact character that were changed, and unified/context diff do not give such results.

`ndiff` returns a "Differ style delta", the bad part is that this is basically an iterator for a list of strings as far as I can see. After the comparison i would like to add line numbers and some other elements to make the comparison clearer.

For example:

File 1:

```
line not in file 2
line different from file 2
```

File 2:

```
line different from file 1
```

The output is:

```
- line not in file 2
- line different from file 2
?                          ^
+ line different from file 1
?                          ^
```

Indicating that the first line from the second file is not in the first file too, and indicating the exact character that was changed.

I would like for the output to be even more explicit, something like:

```
Line 1 from file 2 not found in file 1.
- line not in file 2

Line 2 from file 2 has different characters than in file 2.
- line different from file 2
?                          ^
+ line different from file 1
?                          ^
```

Problem is that for this i need to somehow interpret the mess of strings that ndiff returns. Is there a way to actually get the SequenceMatcher of Differ objects back so I can read and process 1 entire difference at a time rather than 1 line of text?

Also, am I going at this from the wrong angle? Is there a library to do this or something of the sort?

Thank you in advance!